# Sending mass, customized emails from a Rails app hosted on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku

I want to be able to send a monthly email to users of my Rails app hosted on Heroku. However, the email must be customized based on each user's preferences. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: How much customization is necessary? Is the layout (html) completely different or is it just the data used to generate the email custom (i.e. reports, recent activity)

Comment: @dlrust Mostly the data used. For instance, if certain users only want to be notified about certain subjects, the email should only include sections relevant to those subjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sendgrid does the grunt work. Of sending the emails. It's a paid add on.

Since heroku only allows 30 sec of work per request, you need to use a delayed_job or similar to send out all the emails.

You only need to run the worker on heroku when your job is running.